# How do I split items in a list (with delimiter) within a list?

Tags: python, delimiter

UPDATE: Sorry guys, I meant to say a list, within a list.

How do I split items in a list, within another list, using a delimiter. For example:

```
x = [['temp1_a','temp2_b', None, 'temp3_c'],['list1_a','list2_b','list3_c']]
```

Ideally, I would like to split them into a dictionary, so:

```
y = ['temp1','temp2', None, 'temp3','list1','list2','list3']
z = ['a','b', None, 'c','a','b','c']
```

I'm sure it uses split, but when I try using it, I get 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: Do you want a dictionary or two arrays? A dictionary is different than two arrays.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have the list index to match the split item, so: y[0] = z[0] item, etc. Sorry for the confusion, I wish I could just repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list_comprehension.

```
>>> x = ['temp1_a','temp2_b', None, 'temp3_c']
>>> y, z  = [i if i is None else i.split('_')[0] for i in x ], [i if i is None else i.split('_')[1] for i in x ]
>>> y
['temp1', 'temp2', None, 'temp3']
>>> z
['a', 'b', None, 'c']
```

*Update:*

```
>>> x = [['temp1_a','temp2_b', None, 'temp3_c'],['list1_a','list2_b','list3_c']]
>>> y, z = [i if i is None else i.split('_')[0] for i in itertools.chain(*x)], [i if i is None else i.split('_')[1] for i in itertools.chain(*x) ]
>>> y
['temp1', 'temp2', None, 'temp3', 'list1', 'list2', 'list3']
>>> z
['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I should rephrase, and will edit. What if my list, was within a list, so x actually equaled: x = [['temp1_a','temp2_b','temp3_c'],['item1_a','item2_b','item3_c']]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it using [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
xp = [(None,)*2 if i is None else i.split('_') for i in x]
y, z = map(list, zip(*xp))
```

The right-hand side expression on the second line is just an elegant way of writing:

```
[i[0] for i in xp], [i[1] for i in xp]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this...

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> y, z = zip(*([None]*2 if not i else i.split('_') for i in chain(*x)))
>>> y
('temp1', 'temp2', None, 'temp3', 'list1', 'list2', 'list3')
>>> z
('a', 'b', None, 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj i agree, sorry for the confusion, I didn't realize that my list, was within a list. I have still taken note on list comprehensions, and will remember to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's that time of the night, so I thought I'd write a recursive python 3 generator.

```
def flatten_list(a_list):
    for element in a_list:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            yield from flatten_list(element)
        else:
            yield element

# {"temp1": "a", "temp2": "b"...}
values = dict(string.split('_') 
              for string in flatten_list(x)
              if string is not None)
```

Comment: This is maybe a sign that you should go to bed. xD

Comment: I'm convinced this is the reason the `yield from` syntax was introduced.